# QT Installer Controller Script crash while "addWizardPage"

Tags: qt, controller, installation, pixmap

I got some problems with the QT Installer - already done all tutorials (especially http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html) but i am still a real newbie

What i need:

- an installer with a language Selection as first page
- adding a second (save) path in TargetDirectory

What i have:

- an installscript.js (package root)
- an ControlScript.js (path in config.xml)

What i tried in the ControlScript.js:

```
function Controller()
 {
    QMessageBox.information("DEBUG", "DEBUG", "DEBUG", QMessageBox.Ok);
    installer.addWizardPage(component, "Start", QInstaller.Introduction);
    QMessageBox.information("TEST", "TEST", "TEST", QMessageBox.Ok);
 }
```

the Start.ui i placed at the config path and package root but nothing happens... the second MessageBox is never shown - the installer seems to be crashed

```
function Controller()
 {

 }

 Controller.prototype.IntroductionPageCallback = function()
 {
   installer.addWizardPageItem(component ,"lineEdit",QInstaller.TargetDirectory);
 }
```

same - nothing happens here installer crashed

**hope you can help me to fix the code =)**

and can someone please tell me how to change the language or setting a new pixmap (form an existing ressource) while the installer is running?

i wrote this incomplete code in installscript.js:

```
NewLanguageSeted = function()
{
    var widget = gui.pageWidgetByObjectName("DynamicLanguageSelection");
    QMessageBox.information("DEBUG", "DEBUG", "DEBUG", QMessageBox.Ok);
    widget.Icon.setPixmap("");


    installer.languageChanged();
    QMessageBox.information("LanguageSelec", "LanguageSelec", "LanguageSelec", QMessageBox.Ok);

}
```

installer.languageChanged();
will Change all texts based on *.qm files - but how can i get / set the actual language?

widget.Icon.setPixmap("");
changes the pixmap - but i need to know what i have to insert in ""

for the ui file i use a resource file:

```
<property name="pixmap">
      <pixmap resource="../../../resource/resource.qrc">:/DuerrPictures/watermark.png</pixmap>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, installer pages canno't be added from the controller script. If you run the installer from QtCreator, you will see the corresponding debug output, which says something like `component type is not defined`.

To add the page you have to do it inside of the component script (e.g. the constructor). This one will be executed immediatly after you selected one of the 3 checkboxes. The `.ui`-file has to be part of the package, too:

Regarding the second linedit - It is the same problem! The function takes a component as argument - it has to be done inside the `installscript.js`.

installscript.js:

```
function Component()
 {
    QMessageBox.information("DEBUG", "DEBUG", "DEBUG", QMessageBox.Ok);
    installer.addWizardPage(component, "Start", QInstaller.Introduction);
    installer.addWizardPageItem(component ,"lineEdit",QInstaller.TargetDirectory);
    QMessageBox.information("TEST", "TEST", "TEST", QMessageBox.Ok);
 }
```

The pixmap should be settable by using the very same path you used in your .ui-file, i.e. `:/DuerrPictures/watermark.png`. Have your tried that?

And for your language problem - sorry, but I don't know anything about that. Check out the [Scripting API](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-qmlmodule.html) - all script classes are listed there, maybe you can find something.